# Can applications predinstalled in system/priv-app be updated via Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play, android-launcher, custom-rom

We’re trying to make our custom launcher default one in our phone. Since it needs system level permissions (placing widgets) we placed it in `system/priv-ap`p, and it finally works ok. Problem is that it is not updateing with *new version from Play Store - we're getting error 505 after downloading update*, on start of install process